# Telerik WPF RadGridView CurrentItem doesn't work when SelectionMode="Multiple"

Tags: wpf, telerik-grid

Our requirement for the grid is to have checkbox column so that user be able to select multiple items using the checkbox.  During that time, the CurrentItem should be the item user clicked on, which might select/unselect the checkbox, and we will load the detail info of the CurrentItem then display it in a panel outside of the grid.

Here's the definition of the grid:

```
<telerik:RadGridView
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}"
                CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentItem}"
                SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewSelectColumn />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                        Header="Name" />
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

The behavior now is the CurrentItem will always be the first selected item, not the item currently has focus on.

Is there any way to fulfill our requirement?

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set **IsReadOnly** in false:

```
<telerik:RadGridView 
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
         AutoGenerateColumns="False"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}"
         CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentItem}"
         SelectionMode="Multiple"
         RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed">
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewSelectColumn IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"                                          
                 Header="Name" 
                 IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Also added **RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"** for Grid and **IsReadOnly="True"** for 'Name' column